# How do I filter a column in a dataframe for all the entries which contain a certain substring?

Tags: sql, dataframe

I am trying to filter a column in a dataframe for all the entries which contain a certain substring:

[image]

Let's say for the above, i want to filter for all the rows that contain `ada` in their name. So that would be rows 5 and 6 only. I would write something like this:

```
SELECT * from MailList where 'ada' in email
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: python? or where do use your dataframe? and sql uses `LIKE '%ada%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a `SQL` question, you can use `LIKE` operator as:

`... where email like '%ada%'`

Note that I also added the `%` on it that means it will look for the `ada` string anywhere in the name.

as in:

```
blaadable@gmail.com  --> matches
adable@gmail.com  --> matches
ble@gmail.com.ada  --> matches
```

You can also use it (`%`) only as a prefix and/or suffix. As in
`... email like '%ada'` or `email like 'ada%'` It will work accordingly.